# Dynamic Root in routes.rb to own user#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a login section where once someone successfully logs in, I want it to return to their profile user#show. How would you make the routes.rb do this?

Comment: Good question because this leads to some fundamental ideas in Rails that aren't clearly obvious to someone who is new to the technology. Not to imply that only that sort would ask the question, but it's the sort of thing I would have looked for a few months ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In my routes.rb I have

```
  match '/account/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => 'account'
```

In my User Session controller, if they successfully log in then it creates the @current_user_session. Then the @current_user is created. I then route the successful login to the account_path(@current_user) as is defined in the routes.rb

```
  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_session.save
        @current_user_session = UserSession.find
        @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
        format.html { redirect_to(account_path(@current_user), :notice => 'Successfully logged in.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user_session, :status => :created, :location => @user_session }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user_session.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there any flaws on creating the @current_user at this point? Or, any security flaws in

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have something that takes care of the login and menages the session.

Say you have a session controller, to log in a new session is created. (the login form creates a new session, This sends a post to the session's create method, if the username-password combination is correct you do

```
redirect_back_or user
```

your routes.rb has

```
resources :users
```

here is the example for a session controller

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
     def new
       @title = "Sign in"
     end

```
 def create
   user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:name],
     params[:session][:password])
   if user.nil?
     flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
     @title = "Sign in"
     render 'new'
   else
     sign_in user
     redirect_to user
   end
 end

 def destroy
   sign_out
   redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this in routes.rb . Just program that behaviour in the controller.

Inside your login controller set a `redirect_to show_user_path(@user)`

If you want to configure your routes so that  '/' is '/user/show' then:

```
root :to=>'user#show'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question entirely but my first thought was that I wouldn't manage this in routes.rb. I'm assuming you'd have at the very least:

```
[controller]/[some login type action]
users/show
```

as viable actions. Beyond that I'd use the redirect to move to the users/show action from your successful login.

You might look at this link on [redirects](http://www.railsrocket.com/redirecting-in-rails) and this one on [layouts and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for further information...